# Show time after saving a file

Tags: save

After saving a file in Vim, I get the message at the bottom of the screen `"fileName" 92L, 3554C written`. Is there a way to show the time in this message?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can change the string by itself but you can use an autocommand to echo the date:

```
augroup SAVING
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost * echo strftime('%c')
augroup END
```

On my machine it shows something like that:

[image]

An autocommand allows you to execute a command when a given event happens. Here we use the event `BufWritePost` which is triggered when a buffer is written to a file. The command we use is `echo strftime()` which echos the result of `strftime()` which returns a formatted date and time, you can check the doc to change the formatting if needed.

See

- [`:h :augroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup)
- [`:h BufWritePost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufWritePost)
- [`:h strftime()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strftime%28%29)

Answer (score 4):

Different approach: I have the save time as part of my statusline:

```
set statusline=%f               " filename relative to current $PWD
set statusline+=%h              " help file flag
set statusline+=%m              " modified flag
set statusline+=%r              " readonly flag
set statusline+=\ [%{&ff}]      " Fileformat [unix]/[dos] etc...
set statusline+=\ (%{strftime(\"%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M\",getftime(expand(\"%:p\")))})  " last modified timestamp
set statusline+=%=              " Rest: right align
set statusline+=%l,%c%V         " Position in buffer: linenumber, column, virtual column
set statusline+=\ %P            " Position in buffer: Percentage

set laststatus=2
```

To be honest I once copied that from somewhere (maybe stackoverflow) and it stayed in my `vimrc`.

The option `laststatus=2` always displays the statusline.